# ASP.NET CORE MVC Content-Length Header Not Set When OutputFormatter is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with one of my projects. Here is my setup:

I've a template of a ASP.NET Core Web Application. The only thing I've added to the config is at `Startup.cs`

```
.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
        }
```

In my `HomeController` I've the following code:

```
public MyModel Index()
    {
        var message = new MyModel
        {
            PropOne = "Yo Man",
            PropTwo = "Hello Mvc"
        };
        return message;
    }
```

When I run this, and send a request, the response is serialized to XML, but the `Content-Length` header is not set. Can anyone tell me how can I include this header in the headers? Here is a screenshot from the browser:
[image: Browser headers]